# Airflow - Debugging CTE with dynamic dates and Flattened JSON Variables - Snowflake Operator

Tags: sql, t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow

In my sql_file, I'm setting a few variables and running a CTE, but I'm not quite sure which is the problem area. I have a few variables that set my date range and a variable containing a JSON object that I'm flattening later so I can use as a variable list. I'm suspicious it has something to do with the quote identifiers?

This is the error I receive from Airflow, but I can't find an issue with the line/position provided.

```
SQL compilation error:
parse error line 5 at position 65 near '<EOF>'
```

Here's a simplified example of my script.

```
SET MAX_DATE =
(
    SELECT 
            CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, SALES_DATE, CURRENT_DATE()) > 7
                THEN DATEADD(DAY, 7, SALES_DATE)
                ELSE SALES_DATE
            END
    FROM SALES
    LIMIT 1
);

SET MIN_DATE = DATEADD(WEEK, -52, $MAX_DATE);

SET KEY_STORES = 
    '["STORE A","STORE B","STORE C","STORE D"]'
;


WITH SALES AS 
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    SALES_ORDERS SO
    WHERE 
            SO.SALES_DATE BETWEEN $MIN_DATE AND $MAX_DATE
),

STORES AS
(
    SELECT
            VALUE::VARCHAR(50) AS STORE_NAME
    FROM    TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON($KEY_STORES)))
)

SELECT
        *
FROM    SALES
INNER JOIN STORES 
        ON SALES.STORE = STORES.STORE_NAME
;
```

Any guesses on what might be giving me issue?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using airflow. There are many, many, many better options out there.

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON` parsing is correct; the only problem is that you are naming the `CTEs` as the same names as some tables, which is confusing.

My suggestion is to rename the CTEs :

```
WITH SALES_CTE AS 
(
    SELECT  *
    FROM    SALES_ORDERS SO
    WHERE 
            SO.SALES_DATE BETWEEN $MIN_DATE AND $MAX_DATE
),
STORES_CTE AS
(
    SELECT
            VALUE::VARCHAR(50) AS STORE_NAME
    FROM    TABLE(FLATTEN(INPUT => PARSE_JSON($KEY_STORES)))
)
SELECT *
FROM    SALES_CTE sac
INNER JOIN STORES_CTE stc
        ON sac.STORE = stc.STORE_NAME;
```